# Symfony apcu class loader not found, upgrade from 2.8 to 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, apcu

I've upgraded from Symfony version 2.8 to 3.4 everything worked fine locally, but this may be because it was using app_dev.php however in production I get

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\\Component\\ClassLoader\\ApcClassLoader' not found in web/app.php
```

However this file is there in the vendor folder.  It could be that my configuration of app.php is from 2.8 as below, how would I change this work with apcu cache, which I'm aware is deprecated, but currently my caching relies a lot on this.

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance.
// Change 'sf2' to a unique prefix in order to prevent cache key conflicts
// with other applications also using APC.

$apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader('123456etc', $loader);
//$loader->unregister();

$apcLoader->register(true);


require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod',true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
//Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Symfony deprecated its class loader altoger. Instead you should use composer's autoloader which allows you to create an optimized autoloader, including one utilizing apcu: [`composer dump-autoload --apcu`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-). That being said, the [ApcClassLoader](https://github.com/symfony/class-loader/blob/3.4/ApcClassLoader.php) should still be available in Symfony 3.4, as it was removed in 4.0. Can you show your composer.json for your project? Are you requiring symfony/symfony or each component separately?

Comment: @dbrumann that's it the autoloader worked, though I had to change app.php the version used in symfony 3.4